# Get binded value from class property, DefaultBindingProperty is not working for me!

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, class, attributes

I'm creating some entities (class) for my project and I want to set a default binging property for it, here is an example

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("Name")]
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class Family
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Person Father { get; set; }
    }
}
```

if I have `List<Family>` and want to bind it to a GridView and added this field `<asp:BoundField DataField="Father" />` the result will be `MyNamespace.Person` but I need it to populate the value of the property `Name` without using `TemplateField` so did I miss something? or `DefaultBindingProperty` is not the right Attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the the property `Father` is of the type `Person`. There is no obvious string representation of a `Person` value, so the name of the type is displayed. Try to override the `ToString` method to show what you want:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I works, thank you.
So DefaultBindingProperty has nothing to do with this, so what is DefaultBindingProperty purpose?

Comment: My interpretation is that the intended use of `DefaultBindingProperty` is exactly this, but that the control for some reason do not use the information.

Comment: Only problem with this solution is if you're binding to an interface and not to the implementation.  When binding to an interface, the ToString() override doesn't get called.